# Getting text from <span> within a <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the html I am working with there is this approximate structure:

```
...
<span class="priceValue">
  ...
  <span id="asd...">
    12345
  </span>
</span>
...
```

I want to get the number that is the *.text() of the second  (the nested one). The problem is that I cannot use the "id=" property.

Any ideas for the jQuery code needed?

Comment: $('.priceValue span').text();

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot use the id? In other words, do you want to (but its not working), or are you checking for alternatives?

Comment: in a side note.. Do not nest SPAN. Use div outside and span inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the *first* `span` within the *first* `.priceValue` element, then:

```
var text = $(".priceValue > span").first().text();
```

```js
var text = $(".priceValue > span").first().text();
snippet.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="priceValue">
  <div>Not me</div>
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Not me</span>
</div>
<div class="priceValue">
  <div>Not me</div>
  <span>Two</span>
  <span>Not me</span>
</div>
<hr>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you have several `.priceValue` elements and need the text of the first span inside each of them, it's a bit trickier:

```
var textArray = $(".priceValue").map(function() {
  return $(this).children("span").first().text();
  }).get();
```

```js
var textArray = $(".priceValue").map(function() {
  return $(this).children("span").first().text();
  }).get();
snippet.log(textArray.join(", "));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="priceValue">
  <div>Not me</div>
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Not me</span>
</div>
<div class="priceValue">
  <div>Not me</div>
  <span>Two</span>
  <span>Not me</span>
</div>
<hr>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span>span").text(); // direct descendant use this

$("span span").text(); // if don't know if next span is direct descendant
```